# How do I call a function within ajax using codeigniter to update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to call a model function within ajax to update the data the should be in the database.

My main function controller:

```
function m_addR(){
    $this->load->view('m_add_view');
}
```

this other function in my controller is the one that I want to call from my m_add_view to edit data in the database with ajax while remaining in my m_add_view.

what I am thinking is that it should execute the function m_update without leaving m_add_view view as to not have to reload the page.

```
function m_update($id, $text, $column_name){
    $data = array('text'=>$text);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update($column_name, $data);
}
```

this is the code that I have so far to update is:

```
function edit_data(id, text, column_name){
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>control/m_update",
        method:"POST",
        data:{
            id:id,
            text:text,
            column_name:column_name
        },
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
            /*alert(data);*/
            $('#infomsg').show();
        }
    });
}
```

I want to know how to send id, text and colum_name to my m_update function to update the database behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to update it.

```
function m_update(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $text = $this->input->post('text');
    $column_name = $this->input->post('column_name');
    $data = array($column_name => $text);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('table_name', $data);
}
```